# How to Identify and kill a WebSocket on client side?

Tags: javascript, websocket, client, client-server, amazon-transcribe

I'm using a react package(@aws-sdk/client-transcribe-streaming) which opens up a socket for converting speech to text. But this library has a [bug](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/3922) and isn't able to kill the
socket.

Is there any way we can identify that a websocket is hanging on in a browser and then kill it by force?

[image]

Comment: From your git link for the library, there's a workaround available: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/2428

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Again, as I mentioned in the comment of that bug, the issue is different from what I'm facing.